# xcode 4.2 incompatible with ios6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have vmware running OS X 10.6, therefore had do download xcode 4.2 because 4.5 was incompatible with OS X 10.6.  And now it seems I cant create an .ipa file from the app I built  bc my iphone has iOS 6.

Is there a work around for all of this so i can create an the .ipa file using my ios6 device?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Update Mac OS X to 10.8

Comment: Why can't you create an ipa file with Xcode 4.2? What does the version of iOS on your iPhone have to do with creating an ipa file? The ipa file is created in Xcode, not on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think xCode 4.2 is able to build iOS6 IPAs.
Since iOS 6 introduces some new features like auto-layout, which is only available in xCode 4.5

So I recommend you upgrade your OS to use xCode 4.5 instead, which is also recommended by Apple that the developer should use the lastest OS X.